# Meaning of "that of"

Tags: sentence-structure

> The United States spends a paltry $1.35 per person per year on the Corporation for Public Broadcasting, despite polling that indicates that Public Broadcasting Service television programming is more trusted than ***that of*** its for-profit, private competitors.

can ***that of*** replaced by ***polling that indicates***?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be replaced by your suggested phrase. The antecedent of "that" is "television programming".
The PBS television programming is more trusted than television programming of their competitors.